# Undefined method '+' for #<Class >

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, nomethoderror

I created a Rails app to allow visitors to read magazines online. I created two scaffolds, one for the magazine itself and one for the pages inside the magazines, that will be scanned images.

The thing is, I use the pages number (an integer) as reference instead of the id, since I want the the magazine's first page's url to look like so : `localhost:3000/magazines/magazine-test/1`, instead of its ID. So, when uploading a new magazine, I create a loop that increments the pagazine page's number with the help of the loop's index.

Here is my "create" action so that you have a good view of what I'm talking about:

```
def create
    @magazine = Magazine.new(magazine_params)

    if @magazine.save
      (params[:images] || []).each_with_index do |image, index|
        @magazine.pages.create(image: image, page_number: index + 1)
      end
      redirect_to @magazine, notice: 'Magazine créé'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

My issue is that if I try to update this magazine and add a few more pages, the page numbers will fall back to 1. So I tried to edit my "update" action as following:

```
def update
    if @magazine.update(magazine_params)
      if params[:images]
        (params[:images] || []).each_index do |image, index|
          @pages = @magazine.pages.order("page_number DESC").first
          @magazine.pages.create(image: image, page_number: @pages + index + 1)
        abort(@pages)
        end
      end
      redirect_to @magazine, notice: 'Magazine mis à jour'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

However, with this method, I get the following error: `NoMethodError in MagazinesController#update
undefined method '+' for #<Page:0x007fe694b15af8>`

I tried a few things (like converting the variable into integer), but I still get this error.

Anyone as an idea ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line:

```
@magazine.pages.create(image: image, page_number: @pages + index + 1)
```

to

```
@magazine.pages.create(image: image, page_number: @pages.page_number || 0 + index + 1)
```

Comment: I tried this, I got the following error: `nil can't be coerced into Fixnum`

Comment: I made an edit, ugly and hacky, but should give you an idea how to work it out

Comment: || means "or" so if @pages.page_number returns nil it will use 0

Comment: you can also add default value to model, not a good idea to have integer value like this and leave it to chance if its required ....

Comment: I now get `no implicit conversion of nil into String`, does it mean that @page.page_number is equal to nil?

Comment: can you paste that line in the comment?

Comment: also, are you sure you want to use .each_index as opposed to .each_with_index ?

Comment: Ok you just got me to see what was wrong, my "each_index" insteaf of "each_with_index" was why I got all these problems, so thank you!